# Definite integral of unknown function given some additional info

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Given

1. $f$ integrable on [0,3]
2. $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = 1$,
3. $f(x+1) = \frac{1}{2}f(x)$ for all x $\in [0, 2]$

How can I find $\displaystyle\int_0^3 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$ ?

I tried breaking it into as follows:

$\displaystyle\int_0^3 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x = \displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + \displaystyle\int_1^2 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + \displaystyle\int_2^3 f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here...it's been a long time since I took calculus, and I am probably forgetting something really basic. I feel like the solution has something to do with substitution or the fundamental theorem. I notice that 1 and 2 are 0+1, 1+2 so substituting x+1 into f(x), or something along those lines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Breaking the integral is a good idea to start. Proceed as follows:

$\int_{0}^{3}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx+\int_{1}^{3}f(x)dx=1+\int_{1}^{3}f(1+(x-1))dx$

$=1+\int_{0}^{2}f(1+u)du$

by the change of variables theorem and by identity $1$.

Then we have that,

$=1+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2}f(u)du=1+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}f(u)du+\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{2}f(u)du=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{1}^{2}f(1+(u-1))du$.

by identity $1$ and $3$. Now by the change of variables theorem and identities $1$ and $3$ we get

$\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}f(1+z)dz=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{7}{4}$.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Comment: You're welcome. Hope it helps you understand.

Answer (score 0):

That's a good start, and what you noticed is the right idea to finish; for any function $g$ and any values $a,b,c$, it is true that
$$\int_a^bg(x)\,dx=\int_{a-c}^{b-c}g(x+c)\,dx.$$

Comment: Thanks! Is this derived from some other property? I don't recall learning this when I took calculus...

Comment: It's a very easy case of $u$-substitution: let $u=x+c$, so that $du=dx$, and $$x=a\iff u=a-c,\qquad x=b\iff u=b-c.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$\int_1^2f(t)\,dt=\int_0^1f(x+1)\,dx={1\over 2}\int_0^1f(x)\,dx={1\over 2}$$

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to recognize that

$$\int_1^2 dx \, f(x) = \frac12 \int_0^1 dx \, f(x)$$

etc.  Because

$$\int_0^1 dx \, f(x) = 1$$

then

$$\int_0^3 dx \, f(x) = 1+\frac12+\frac14 = \frac{7}{4}$$

Comment: Thanks! I guess this works because of the property mentioned by Zev Chonoles (When the integration limits are changed from a and b to a-c and b-c, then the value at which the function is evaluated changes to x+c)?

Comment: @mhy: yes, that's what I was implicitly saying.